# Loop unrolling for multiplying two matrices NxN?

Tags: c, optimization, loops, for-loop, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to figure out a good Loop unrolling for multiplying two matrices .

For example if we wanted to Sum a NxN matrix :

```
void SumMatrix(int *M, int n, int *result) 
{ 
  int  i,j; 

  *result = 0; 
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) 
      *result += M[j][i]; 
}
```

We can do this :

```
void SumMatrix(int *M, int n, int *result) 
{ 
    int  i; 
    int  size = n*n; 
    int  last = size%8; 
    int  acc1 = 0; 
    int  acc2 = 0; 
    int  *pEnd = M+size-last; 

    for (; M<pEnd; M+=8) 
    { 
      acc1 += (*M + *(M+1)) + (*(M+2) + *(M+3));
      acc2 += (*(M+4) + *(M+5)) + (*(M+6) + *(M+7));
    } 

    /* adding the last entries */ 
    while (last--)  
        acc1 += *(M++); 

    *result = acc1+acc2;        
}
```

But I've tried to find a (GOOD) way to multiply 2 matrices , however found none at the moment .

**Remark** : this is no homework task , I have an exam today and just thought about this question , I think it could be a fine question for an exam , don't you  ?

I'd appreciate any help

Regards

Ron

Comment: Depends on the nature of the exam. If it is specifically about low level performance optimization (with the preconditions that it has been proven by measurements that a) the first code version is a significant performance bottleneck, and b) the second version runs significantly faster in the actual production environment than the first), then fine. If it is about general C programming, definitely not. The first piece of code is way more clean, easy to read, verify and maintain than the second.

Comment: @PéterTörök: No ,take the usual multiplication of two matrices using 3 FOR-loops . I'm trying to make if faster and , with SUMs  , like in the above code .

Comment: I understood what you were trying to do. Did you understand my comment? What is the exam you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most compilers will do the unrolling for you (you might need to turn on a flag, or set it to an optimization level - I believe `-funroll-loops` does it for gcc).

Also, with your question, the fact that it is a 2D matrix doesn't matter, since you are adding all the numbers up. If you are limited to a single process/thread, adding the numbers up sequentially will be the fastest because that has optimal caching performance. You might get some benefit out of SSE or vector instructions; again, today's compilers can do these for you with such a simple problem.

Comment: Thanks ,do you have a piece of code maybe that I can look at ?

Comment: For vectorization with gcc, run simple single-loop summation code with `-ftree-vectorize` to vectorize it; with `-ftree-vectorize-verbose=2`, it'll tell you when compiling which loops it vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Look how complex the ATLAS project is, which provides an optimized version of a BLAS library (based primarily on matrix multiplication). It should consider not only thread-level parallelism, but the memory hierarchy (not only unrolling, but cache tiling and register tiling, software pipelining and so forth). It's usually written by hands or optimized by the "auto-tuner", like ATLAS. In case you want to unravel thread-level parallelism, you'd better to use a "tiled algorithm" and spread the resulting tiles computation between your threads.